# Another PHP regex question

Tags: php, regex

Guys, this probably will be fairly simple, but how am I able to find all the matches using regex of this occurrence in a load of text.

```
[[data in here]]
```

EG:

```
Blah blah blah [[find]] and maybe [[this]]
```

So I am able to find the occurrences and then replace them as urls.

Does that make sense?

I tried using

```
preg_match_all("/[[([^<]*)]]/", $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

But returns errors. Any ideas? :)

Comment: `[` and `]` are special characters in regular expressions and so need to be escaped with `\\`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/", $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using .+? over .* or is it just preference? I can't think of a situation where they would differ.

Comment: .* = matches any character, 0 or more times, as many times as possible

Comment: .+? = matches any character, 1 or more times, as few times as possible

Comment: Interesting. So will they capture different text, or is it just that your version isn't greedy and is presumably less expensive?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ....

```
"/\[.*\]/"
```

? Just a wild guess.

I think your basic problem is that you need to escape the '[]' brackets, as they are special chars.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the '[' and ']' characters - they are special characters in regex. You're probably best off doing this with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

```
function makeURL($matches) {
    $url = $matches[1];
    return "<a href=\"http://$url\">$url</a>";
}

$data = 'My website is [[www.example.com]].';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/', 'makeURL', $data);

// output: My website is <a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>
```

You can tweak the `makeURL()` function to re-write the URL however you please.

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `]` have meaning in regular expression syntax.  To match them, you need "escape" them using the `\` character.  So your regular expression would be:

```
"/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/"
```

The usage of the `[` and `]` characters and how to escape them is pretty basic regular expression knowledge.  Not to be rude, but I suggest spending a little more time learning regular expressions before you write any for production code.