# What's the difference between these perl compatible regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

An answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286113/another-php-regex-question/1286117#1286117) piqued my curiosity.

Consider:

```
$string = "asfasdfasdfasdfasdf[[sometextomatch]]asfkjasdfjaskldfj";

$regex = "/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/";
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);

$regex = "/\[\[(.*)\]\]/"; 
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
```

I asked what the difference between the two regexes is. The aswer I got was that ".*" matches any character 0 or more times as many times as possible,
and ".+?" matches any character 1 or more times as few times as possible.

I read those regexes differently so I did some experimenting on my own but didn't come to any conclusions. Php.net says "?" is equivalent to {0,1} so you could rewrite

```
"/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/"
```

as

```
"/\[\[((.+){0,1})\]\]/"
```

or as

```
"/\[\[(.{0,})\]\]/"
```

or as

```
"/\[\[(.*)\]\]/"
```

Will they capture different text? Is the difference that one is less expensive? Am I being anal?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I wonder how many broken regex's I've written having overlooked this important detail. I gave Gumbo the check because that answer was the clearest to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take an example where you get different results:

```
foo [[bar]] baz [[quux]]
```

Your first regular expression will match `[[bar]]` and `[[quux]]` while the second will match only `[[bar]] baz [[quux]]`.

The reason for that is that a lazy [quantifier](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) (suffixed with `?`) will match the minimum of possible repetitions the normal greedy mode will match the maximum of possible repetitions:

> However, if a quantifier is followed by a question mark, then it ceases to be greedy, and instead matches the minimum number of times possible, so the pattern `/\*.*?\*/` does the right thing with the C comments. The meaning of the various quantifiers is not otherwise changed, just the preferred number of matches. Do not confuse this use of question mark with its use as a quantifier in its own right. Because it has two uses, it can sometimes appear doubled, as in `\d??\d` which matches one digit by preference, but can match two if that is the only way the rest of the pattern matches.

Answer (score 3):

Stand-alone, `?` does mean `{0,1}`, however, when it follows something like `*`, `+`, `?`, or `{3,6}` (for example), `?` means something else entirely, which is that it does minimal matching. So, no, you can't rewrite `/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/` as `/\[\[((.+){0,1})\]\]/`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `?` means "capture the preceding thing 0 or 1 times". However, when used after a `*` or `+`, a `?` modifies the meaning of the `*` or `+`. Normally, `*`/`+` mean "match 0 (1 for +) or more times, and match as many as possible". Adding the `?` modifies that meaning to be "match 0 (1 for +) or more times, but match as few as possible". By default those expressions are "greedy", `?` modifies them to be non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` will only capture it one time ( the `(0,1)` means 0 to 1 times) where as the `*` will capture it as many times as it occurs in the string.

From [this page:](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

> If you take `<.+>` and use it on `The <em>Big</em> Dog.` it will give `<em>Big</em>`. Where as `<.+?>` will only match `<em>`

Answer (score 0):

```
/.*/   ===  /.{0,}/
/.+/   ===  /.{1,}/
/.?/   ===  /.{0,1}/
```

```
"aaaaaa" =~ /a*/;  # "aaaaaa"
"aaaaaa" =~ /a*?/; # ""
```